# find average/mean of specific column value string

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find average/mean of specific value in specific column, the value is string

Lets say this is the table

```
RAM     Screen_Size    Resolution       SSD     HDD     Weight    Price
8       15.6           1920 x 1080      512     512     1.90      807.00
12      17.0           2560 x 1600      1000    512     2.00      1500.00
64      15.0           1920 x 1080      512     256     2.50      2000.00
32      14.0           2560 x 1600      1000    512     2.30      1750.00
```

I want to know the average of all column for specific value of 1920 x 1080

so the output will be like this (maybe)

```
              RAM     Screen_Size    Resolution   SSD   HDD     Weight    Price
1920 x 1080    xxx    xxxx            xxxx        xx    xxx     xxxx      xxxx
```

Comment: Try: `df.groupby('Resolution', as_index=False).mean()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
df.groupby('Resolution', as_index=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
    Resolution   RAM  Screen_Size     SSD    HDD  Weight   Price
0  1920 x 1080  36.0         15.3   512.0  384.0    2.20  1403.5
1  2560 x 1600  22.0         15.5  1000.0  512.0    2.15  1625.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_data = []
for key, sample in df.groupby('Resolution'):
    del sample['Resolution']
    sample = sample.apply(lambda x: x.astype(float))
    new_data.append([key]+sample.mean().values.tolist())

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
new_df.columns = ['Resolution', 'RAM',
                  'Screen_Size', 'SSD', 'HDD', 'Weight', 'Price']
new_df
```

Output

```
    Resolution  RAM     Screen_Size     SSD     HDD     Weight  Price
0   1920x1080   36.0    15.3            512.0   384.0   2.20    1403.5
1   2560x1600   22.0    15.5            1000.0  512.0   2.15    1625.0
```